# .Net Equivalent of set_unexpected()

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-2.0, unhandled

Is there a .net equivalent to the C++ unexpected()/set_unexpected() functionality?

---

**Edit:**  Sorry--I omitted some details previously:

Language: C# 2.0

I have some legacy apps that seem to be throwing some unhandled exception somewhere.  I just want to put something in place to stop the customer's pain until I can trace the actual source of the problem.  In C++, the function pointed at by set_unexpected() gets called, as far as I know, when an otherwise unhandled exception bubbles to the main routine.  Hence my question about a .net equivalent functionality.

Comment: Could you give more detail about what effect you're trying to achieve overall? Chances are the idiomatic way in .NET won't exactly mirror unexpected/set_unexpected.

Comment: Yes, Jon, I can see what you're saying.  I realized after I posted my question that I did sort of skimp on details.  I will edit appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There 3 possible scenarios for handling unhandled exceptions, based on the type of the application:

1. For windows forms application, hook an event handler to [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)
2. For commandline applications, hook an event handler to [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)
3. For ASP.NET applications, in Global.asax, create:

   protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)

DISCLAIMER: I'm not c++ developer, but from what I read, this should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

These handlers should catch most unexpected exceptions in your mixed-mode application.

```
private delegate long UnhandledExceptionFilter(IntPtr exception);

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetUnhandledExceptionFilter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] UnhandledExceptionFilter filter);

// put these in your bootstrapper
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionFilter);

void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

long UnhandledExceptionFilter(IntPtr exception)
{
    ....
}
```